# Finding number of pairs of integers differing by a value

Tags: algorithm

If we have an array of integers, then is there any efficient way other than O(n^2) by which one can find the number of pairs of integers which differ by a given value?
E.g for the array 4,2,6,7 the number of pairs of integers differing by 2 is 2 {(2,4),(4,6)}.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a set from your list.  Create another set which has all the elements incremented by the delta.  Intersect the two sets.  These are the upper values of your pairs.

In Python:

```
>>> s = [4,2,6,7]
>>> d = 2
>>> s0 = set(s)
>>> sd = set(x+d for x in s0)
>>> set((x-d, x) for x in (s0 & sd))
set([(2, 4), (4, 6)])
```

Creating the sets is O(n). Intersecting the sets is also O(n), so this is a linear-time algorithm.

Comment: It's linear time in the average case (assuming you use hash tables), worst-case performance is worse.

Comment: Python sets are implemented with a hash table, and yes, the expected time.

Answer (score 3):

Store the elements in a multiset, implemented by a hash table. Then for each element `n`, check the number of occurences of `n-2` in the multiset and sum them up. There is no need to check `n+2` because that would cause you to count each pair twice.

The time efficiency is O(n) in the average case, and O(n*logn) or O(n^2) in the worst case (depending on the hash table implementation). It will be O(n*logn) if the multiset is implemented by a balanced tree.

Comment: Beat me to it; +1. This algorithm is expected O(n) if a hash table is used, and guaranteed O(n lg n) if a red-black tree is used.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the array, then scan through with two pointers. Supposing the first one points to `a`, then step the second one forward until you've found where `a+2` would be if it was present. Increment the total if it's there. Then increment the first pointer and repeat. At each step, the second pointer starts from the place it ended up on the previous step.

If duplicates are allowed in the array, then you need to remember how many duplicates the second one stepped over, so that you can add this number to the total if incrementing the first pointer yields the same integer again.

This is `O(n log n)` worst case (for the sort), since the scan is linear time.

It's `O(n)` worst case on the same basis that hashtable-based solutions for fixed-width integers can say that they're expected O(n) time, since sorting fixed-width integers can be done using radix sort in O(n). Which is actually faster is another matter -- hashtables are fast but might involve a lot of memory allocation (for nodes) and/or badly-localized memory access, depending on implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if the desired difference is 0 and all the elements in the array are identical, then the size of the output is O(n²), so the worst-case of any algorithm is necessarily O(n²). (On the other hand, average-case or expected-case behavior can be significantly better, as others have noted.)

Comment: The output is the number of pairs, not the list of pairs.

Comment: You're right, the output is the number of pairs. I misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just hash the numbers in an array as you do in counting sort.Then take two variables, first pointing to index 0 and the other pointing to index 2(or index d in general case) initially.
Now check whether value at both indices are non-zero, if yes then increment the counter with larger of the two values else leave the counter unchanged as the pair does not exist. Now increment both the indices and continue until the second index reaches the end of the array.The total value of counter is the number of pairs with difference d. 
Time complexity: O(n)
Space complexity: O(n)